# Displaying Unicode character on Virtual Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, fonts, unicode

This question is an extension of this: - [How to display unicode in a Linux virtual terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/556993/how-to-display-unicode-in-a-linux-virtual-terminal)

I am using Ubuntu Linux and I have a file (abc.txt) with UTF-8 encoding. It has Unicode character 'घ' inside.

But when I am on Virtual terminal (opened using Ctrl + Alt + F2). On typing

```
cat abc.txt
```

it is displaying a diamond instead of the character 'घ'. I want that unicode character 'घ' displayed on the virtual Terminal. I think maybe it is related to font issue, but not sure. However, on X term, the character 'घ' is displayed correctly

I have also searched and found that this is 'resolved' by installing tool jfbterm, but I dont want that. I want the character to be displayed on the 'raw' virtual terminal

System Config - Linux jingle 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux